# Jquery plugin - inline editing .. how to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to use ToggleEdit in MVC3 and Jquery page.. here is the link
http://staticvoid.info/toggleEdit/... although there are lot of demo samples in this page, i really dont understand how to make this work in a View. I am new to Jquery and MVC.

Step 1: I referenced the Jquery plug in at the top of the page..

```
<link href="../../Content/themes/base/toggleEdit.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.toggleEdit.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Step 2: Some how have this Jquery triggered in the HTML.. view.

```
  <table>

  @foreach (var item in Model) 

  {

   <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)
    </td>
    </tr>

  }
   </table>
```

How do I change this view code and make use of this Jquery plug in. Thanks for your help. On Click on the row or a item (cell) in the row, inline editing should be activated. And saved.

Here is an example of a sample from the source website.. How do I actually implement something like this for my table HTML fields?

```
   $(el).find('input,select').toggleEdit({
events: {
    edit: 'mouseenter'
}
   });
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a full example that I wrote for you and that should put you on the right track.

As always you start with a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller to populate this view model and pass it to the view:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // TODO: Fetch from a repository instead of hardcoding
        var model = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => new MyViewModel
        {
            Name = "name " + x,
            Phone = "phone " + x
        });
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

then a view (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @Html.EditorForModel()
    </tbody>
</table>

<a id="toggleEdit" href="#">Toggle edit</a>
```

then the corresponding editor template which will be rendered for each element of our view model (`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/MyViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model MyViewModel
<tr>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Phone)</td>
</tr>
```

and finally the scripts and styles that we need to include:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.toggleEdit.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.toggleEdit.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#toggleEdit').click(function () {
            $('table :input').toggleEdit();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to see this..thank you for the wonderful code sample.. you rock Darin.

Comment: I just tried it out. Looks like this is my problem with this. When the page loads and the table is rendered, it appears to have text boxes that are editable to begin with. I like a solid text like cells where on click the cell becomes editable. Also I am not able to update the record.. I mean save it. How do I make it pass through a actionmethod in a controller code to run the save code..

Comment: In Darin's solution above.. the toggle edit is triggered only by clicking on a <a > link.. I would like that to trigger on click on a row cell directly for user to edit. For that to happen, the initial display on page load needs to show the cells as 'plain text' solid cells ..only on click should they be available to edit.

Comment: I fixed one issue.. Kind of. I took the <a> link out and added the id = toggleedit to a <tr> tag.. so instead of triggering the Jquery on <a> click .. now I can click on a row of the table and edit the contents...thats working for all rows except the first row of the table. Wonder why.

Comment: jquery gets angry if you have duplicate ids on the page

Comment: For the following to work you would need to give each row a css class of editable. Doing it this way so that it doesn't attach to the header row.                                                   $(function () {
        $('tr.editable').click(function () {
            $(this).find(':input').toggleEdit();
            return false;
        });
    });

Answer (score -1):

it's better to write your own jquery validation script it's very easy , if you really want to learn just leave me a email at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, i will send you the script and will explain you every step , pasting entire code here will not make sense...good luck